# Is this Quadrilateral possible?

Tags: geometry, rectangles, quadrilateral

[image: Quadrilateral Image]

Is this figure possible to achieve?

$AD > BC$; $\angle BCD$ = $\angle BAD$ = $90^{\circ}$ .

And this is supposed to be a closed quadrilateral.

I'm confused as to whether this is viable - since $AD > BC$, and the angles are $90^{\circ}$, how would this figure close?

Comment: $BD$ is the hypotenuse for both $BCD$ and $ABD$.  So use Pythagoras to find $BD$ and then $AB$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure seems perfectly alright.
The confusion in your mind may be because you are considering the angle at D to be $90^{\circ}$. Imagine it to be an acute angle and then it would be fine.
Note that one of the hypotenuse BD is $\sqrt{34}$ by pythagorus theorem. And hence the remaining side is of length $4$.
Try to draw the figure with $D$ as an acute angle and your confusion would be clear.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly the problem, thanks.